# What should I do to save files in the right directory in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am creating a website in Flask, in which ideally after pasting my report and adding the report name, the website would save the newly generated report in `static/{report_name}/new_file.txt` and a Graphviz file (in `static/{report_name}/graph.gv`).

Here is my current js and HTML code that I am using:

```js
async function summarize() {
  // Get the text area element
  const text = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
  const reportname = document.getElementById("reportname").value;
  // Get the summarize button element
  const summarizeButton = document.getElementById("summarize");

  // Add an event listener to the summarize button
  summarizeButton.addEventListener("click", async() => {
    // Get the text from the text area
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Add the text to the FormData object
    formData.append("text", text);
    formData.append("reportname", reportname);
    // Save the user's input in a file named "input.txt" in the report folder
    fetch("../save_input", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        text,
        reportname
      }),
    });

    // Save the selected graph in a file named "graph.gv" in the report folder
    const graph = document.getElementById("selGraph").value;
    fetch("../save_graph", {
      method: "POST",
      body: graph,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      },
    });
    const graphText = await fetch(graph).then(response => response.text());
    fetch(`../static/reports/${reportname}/graph.gv`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: graphText,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      },
    });

    // Reload the page to display the Step2 content
    document.getElementById("Step2").click();
  });

}
```

```html
<p>Please add your report into this box: </p>
<br />
<textarea id="paragraph" , aria-labelledby="TextforReport" />
</textarea>
<p>Please add the report name into this box: </p>
<br />
<textarea id="reportname" ,aria-labelledby="Textforname" />
</textarea>
<br />
```

And here are my code in Flask for the server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import subprocess
import os
@app.route('/save_input', methods=['POST'])
def save_input():
    data = request.get_json()
    paragraph = data.get('text')
    reportname = data.get('reportname')
    # Create a directory for the report if it doesn't already exist
    if not os.path.exists(f'static/reports/{reportname}'):
        os.makedirs(f'static/reports/{reportname}')
    # Save the input to a file named "input.txt" in the report folder
    with open(f'static/reports/{reportname}/input.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(paragraph)
    return 'OK'

@app.route('/save_graph', methods=['POST'])
def save_graph():
    graph = request.data.decode('utf-8')
    reportname = request.form.get('reportname')
    # Create a directory for the report if it doesn't already exist
    if not os.path.exists(f'static/reports/{reportname}'):
        os.makedirs(f'static/reports/{reportname}')
    # Save the graph to a file named "graph.gv" in the report folder
    with open(f'static/reports/{reportname}/graph.gv', 'w') as file:
        file.write(graph)
    return 'OK'
```

However, when I run the code in Flask, the directory with the report name is not created, and Flask returned this error for me (the report name is Emotet in this case, so the directory should be `static/reports/Emotet`):

[image]

So what did I do wrong in this case, and what should I do to save both of my files in the right directory?

Comment: `405` is `Method Not Allowed` maybe because you are using a `POST` method without a base for `post` like a `form` in html.

Comment: format the `reportname` according to the linux file sys

Comment: I have looked into the Linux file system, but how could I be able to reformat the `reportname` given that my OS is in Windows?