# Why I could not paste a file to a folder named from FormData in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am currently creating a form to save my report, as well as my output (`Final_Graph.gv`) to a folder (with report name provided: `static/reports/{reportname}`). Following my earlier question: [What should I do to save files in the right directory in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76182588/what-should-i-do-to-save-files-in-the-right-directory-in-flask), I have reformatted the code in JavaScript and HTML like this:

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->


async function summarize() {
  // Get the text area element
  const text = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
  const reportname = document.getElementById("reportname").value;
  // Get the summarize button element
  const summarizeButton = document.getElementById("summarize");

  // Add an event listener to the summarize button
  summarizeButton.addEventListener("click", async() => {
    // Get the text from the text area
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Add the text to the FormData object
    formData.append("text", text);
    formData.append("reportname", reportname);
    // Save the user's input in a file named "input.txt" in the report folder
    fetch("../save_input", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        text,
        reportname
      }),
    });

    fetch("../save_graph", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ reportname: reportname })
  });

    // Reload the page to display the Step2 content
    //document.getElementById("Step2").click();
  });

}
```

```html
<p>Please add your report into this box: </p>
<br />
<textarea id="paragraph" , aria-labelledby="TextforReport" />
</textarea>
<p>Please add the report name into this box: </p>
<br />
<textarea id="reportname" ,aria-labelledby="Textforname" />
</textarea>
<br />
```

Here is my current code (in Flask):

```
@app.route('/save_input', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def save_input():
    data = request.get_json()
    paragraph = data.get('text')
    reportname = data.get('reportname').strip()
    # Create a directory for the report if it doesn't already exist
    if not os.path.exists(f'static/reports/{reportname}'):
        os.makedirs(f'static/reports/{reportname}')
    # Save the input to a file named "input.txt" in the report folder
    with open(f'static/reports/{reportname}/report.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(paragraph)
    return 'OK'

@app.route('/save_graph', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def save_graph():
    try:
       reportname = request.get_json().get('reportname').strip()
    # Create a directory for the report if it doesn't already exist
       if not os.path.exists(f'static/reports/{reportname}'):
         os.makedirs(os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'reports', reportname), exist_ok=True)
    
      # Copy the Final_Graph.gv file to the report folder
       src_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'Final_Graph.gv'))
       dst_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'reports', reportname, 'Final_Graph.gv'))
       shutil.copyfile(src_path, dst_path)
       return 'OK'
    except Exception as e:
       app.logger.exception(e)
       return 'Error saving graph'
```

Although `POST` from my server still return a `200` message for `save_graph` function, I could not get the `Final_Graph.gv` saved in my desired position, even after the `save_input` function with the same FormData worked. I got this error from Flask:

```
raise BadRequest(
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.
```

So do you know what did I go wrong in this situation, and how could I be able to fix it?